# 'Access is denied' Javascript error

Tags: javascript

i am opening a file in IE6.0 from a directory using JavaScript.
but iam getting 'Access is denied' error in javascript.My code
in javascript

```
function poponload()
{
testwindow = window.open("C:\Searchtool\asd1.wrl", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=300,height=300");
testwindow.moveTo(0,0);
}
```

if i use the same function from plain html page it is opening the page.
But if i try to do the samething from ASP.NET2008(.ASPX page), i am getting 'access is denied' error. can anybody tell the reason why it is giving error? and Solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to access a file on the hard drive which you aren't allowed to do from a page from a web server.

Comment: For more information, look up the "Same Origin Policy": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 2):

It's a browser security feature.  It won't allow you to directly access the hard drive from a web page.  You can access it when you open an HTML file on the local system -- since the browser isn't granting you any more abilities than you already have, but allowing a web page to open a file on a local hard drive would be a huge security flaw.

The only way I know to do things like this are through trusted plugins/applets -- such as ActiveX or Java Applets.  These need to be signed and/or have the user explicitly trust them with access to your system to get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning html and want a way to open pages in your machine from pages in your machine:

```
window.open("file:///C:/Searchtool/asd1.wrl", "mywindow", "location=1,
    status=1,scrollbars=1,width=300,height=300");
```

Comment: Isn't this possible? Since you can open local pages with `file:///` protocol, I thought it would go well in script too - didn't bother to test it.

Comment: Just tested it and it is possible - why the down-vote then? I specifically said that this can be used only to open pages in your machine from pages in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

better, put files in the same directory where is your web page.